# AWS Code Deploy Agent install

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy

I am going through: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent.html#how-to-run-agent-install-ubuntu

I did exactly what was written in the tutorial, after installing Ruby 2.0.0.....
Unfortunately, it is not working and I cannot find anything in regards of that link, why it is not available. My EC2 instance is running in eu-west-1 (ireland), the aws/config is also configured for that. The IAM has S3, CodeDeploy full Access rights - otherwise I would not have been able to download the install file in the first place.

```
./install auto
I, [2015-09-20T18:08:56.516995 #12388]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.
I, [2015-09-20T18:08:56.517235 #12388]  INFO -- : Starting update check.
I, [2015-09-20T18:08:56.517335 #12388]  INFO -- : Attempting to automatically detect supported package manager type for system...
I, [2015-09-20T18:08:56.578509 #12388]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_REGION environment variable for region information...
I, [2015-09-20T18:08:56.578590 #12388]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for region information...
I, [2015-09-20T18:08:56.597957 #12388]  INFO -- : Downloading version file from bucket aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1 and key latest/VERSION...
E, [2015-09-20T18:08:56.633576 #12388] ERROR -- : Could not find version file to download at 'https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/aws-codedeploy-eu-central-1/latest/VERSION'
```

I hope someone could clarify wheather this is still in use by AWS or if I was missing anything from the "documentation" ?

Answer (score 1):

CodeDeploy is not currently available in `eu-central-1`. See [CodeDeploy supported regions](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/faqs/#regions) for an up to date list.

If you try to use the install script in a live region, such as `eu-west-1` it should work.